# How would SquishIt render a file using to a local directory but write the file reference to a different subdomain

Tags: squishit

Is there a way using SquishIt to render a combined file to a local directory, keeping the filename SquishIt generated, but changing the domain?

So, something like this:

```
Bundle.Css().Add("~/file1.css").Add("~/file2.css").Render("~/content/combined-css_#.css")
```

Normally, SquishIt would render that to a link, replacing the # with a key signature, as something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/content/combined-css_697C70D68EA1DCBE1903A58032BDB305.css" />
```

However, I serve my css and js file from a static cookieless domain. I want the file to be written to the same local directory and still use SquishIt's generated key signature, but I want to output the stylesheet link to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://static.mydomain.com/content/combined-css_697C70D68EA1DCBE1903A58032BDB305.css" />
```

Comment: How did you go about deploying the static CSS/JS files to the CDN?

Comment: @Gene, did you end up deploying the compiled bundles to a CDN? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you would want to use the `WithOutputBaseHref` method. Here is what it looks like:

```
Bundle.Css()
    .Add("~/file1.css")
    .Add("~/file2.css")
    .WithOutputBaseHref("http://static.mydomain.com")
    .Render("~/content/combined-css_#.css")
```

Does it work for you?

Comment: This method didn't seem to be in the 0.8 version, but I updated to 0.84 and works like a charm. Thanks!